# Java - Button in a button

Tags: java, jbutton

I'm making a program with 2 `JButton`, however I have a MyFrame class and the buttons are in a different class named KnoppenPanel. The problem is, when I do this I will get a `JButton` in a `JButton`. So I have my 2 buttons and another Button surrounding these. How do I solve this?

MyFrame:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    Uithangbord u = new Uithangbord();
    KnoppenPanel kp = new KnoppenPanel();

    public MyFrame() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(u);
        add(kp);

        setSize(280, 180);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

public class KnoppenPanel extends JButton implements ActionListener {
private JButton b, b2;
private JPanel p1;

Uithangbord bord = new Uithangbord();

public KnoppenPanel() {
    p1 = new JPanel();
    add(p1);

    b = new JButton("Open");
    p1.add(b);
    b.addActionListener(this);

    b2 = new JButton("Gesloten");
    p1.add(b2);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    JButton knop = (JButton)(event.getSource());
    if (knop == b) {
        b.setEnabled(false);
        b2.setEnabled(true);
        bord.maakOpen();
    }
    if (knop == b2) {
        b2.setEnabled(false);
        b.setEnabled(true);
        bord.maakGesloten();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this? AFAIK a button in a button is not possible (at least not using the standard components) and would not be good design anyways. You could, however, use a clickable panel, is that what you want?

Comment: @Thomas he does not want this to happen, the title is his problem not his goal.

Comment: Btw, `KnoppenPanel extends JButton` is already misleading, I suspect you should extend `JPanel` instead of `JButton`, since you don't seem to actually need `KnoppenPanel` itself to be clickable.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings yes _"button in a button"_ is the problem but why would he do that in the first place? Why extend `JButton` if the panel is no button? So either that's the entire problem or the OP has some intentions that aren't clear yet.

Comment: @Thomas My teacher explained it wrong. He said I needed to extend it with JButton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You class is extending `JButton`. Then when you add your `JPanel` (with 2 `JButton`) you are adding this in a `JButton`.

I think what do you want is the KnoppenPanel have only the 2 `JButtons` then you just need to change:

```
public class KnoppenPanel extends JButton implements ActionListener {
```

By

```
public class KnoppenPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
```

If you do this change, you can also directly add the JButton in the KnoppenPanel like that:

```
public KnoppenPanel() {

    b = new JButton("Open");
    add(b);
    b.addActionListener(this);

    b2 = new JButton("Gesloten");
    add(b2);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
}
```